# Compression of raw resource data, of desktop image frame, from D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE (Desktop Duplication API)

Tags: image, compression, directx-11, desktop-duplication

I need to transfer **frames of desktop image data** over the network, that were captured with Desktop Duplication API, but there is one problem: **size** **of raw frame** data, in **FullHD** with **DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM** format, approximatly equal to 8 **MB**, that too large size, especially for one frame.

Is there something good method to compress the frame, of desktop image, data from **D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE** and get the size at least in **KB**? Maybe some kind of conversion from bmp to jpeg?

I've already tried **LZ4** compression, with **LZ4_compress_default** method, and got byte array with 3.4 **MB** size, that is still too much for frame.

Comment: You need to use some form of lossy compression like ``JPG`` if something lossless like ``PNG`` doesn't meet your size requirements. Note you can use [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) to do this. For some example code, see [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/tree/master/ScreenGrab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...large size, especially for one frame

Since you are doing video and network transmission is in question, the only real choices for you are H.264 and H.265 video compression - those available implemented in hardware assisted encoders on video adapters. Microsoft [Media Foundation API (Transforms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-foundation-transforms) and video hardware vendor specific SDKs offer related functionality.

Windows Imaging Component (WIC) for individual images will be both slower and less efficient in compression ratio. Although it could be a good choice in the case individual snapshots are the only data to transmit, as opposed to video.

Also, an easy way to check out support for video encoding: http://alax.info/blog/1609

> The tools enumerates the transforms and provides details, similar to Enumerating Media Foundation Transforms (MFTs) application

Comment: What method of compression can you advise, if screen capture implemented on clients and frames are sended to server over network within **VDI**? In this case **client can't see real hardware** and, i suppose, **using of Media Foundation**, with H.264 encoder, should be realized on **server side**, where we will use received frames to render the video. On the client side, perhaps, it might be better to use something to compress the raw data and send it over the network.

Comment: Not sure how VDI fits here. If the desktop image is composed on VD server in virtualized environment then it's perhaps server has to deal with video compression. And then - yes - it might have hard time accessing the GPU for compression services.